# comparison between arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays, comparator

I have to develop a code that compares two groups (A & B) of 3 numbers each. If one of the numbers is higher than the other one it receives a point, if both numbers are equal then none of the groups receive a point.

The problem I have is that when 2 numbers are equal the score of the group B increases by one while the score group A doesn't increase. When the numbers are different the program adds correctly the points.

Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    int a[3], b[3], totala=0, totalb=0, final[2]{0,0};

        cin >> a[0];
        cin >> a[1];
        cin >> a[2];
        
        cin >> b[0];
        cin >> b[1];
        cin >> b[2]; 

    if (a[0]>b[0]) {
        totala++;
    } else {
        totalb++;
    }
    if (a[1]>b[1]) {
        totala++;
    } else {
        totalb++;
    }
    if (a[2]>b[2]) {
        totala++;
    } else {
        totalb++;
    }
    if (a[0]==b[0]) {
        totala = totala;
        totalb =totalb;
    } else if(a[1]==b[1]) {
        totala = totala;
        totalb =totalb;
    } else if(a[2]==b[2]) {
        totala = totala;
        totalb =totalb;
    }
    
    final[0] = totala;
    final[1] = totalb;

    cout << final[0] << " " << final [1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This weird behaviour is because of missing conditions in if-else.

So if you dry run the code you are just checking the greater inequality and if not fulfilled then increasing the other variable and that's creating the whole mess.
Instead of incrementing those variables in else statements modify with else if (less than inequality), as you are handling equalities in separate ifs.

FYI -> Try to reducing if-else by nested if-else and use for loop if group size is not fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to reorganize you `if-else` logic.

```cpp
    if (a[0]>b[0]){
        totala++;
    } else if (a[0]==b[0]){
        // nothing
    } else {
        totalb++;
    }
    // if (a[0]==b[0]) { // do not compare them again
```

Answer (score 0):

when two numbers are equal, such as `a == b`then neither of them are greater or less than the other, so when `a == b`  `if (a > b) { /*statement1*/ } else { /*statement2*/ }` execute statement2.

Answer (score 0):

Working code below, first you initialize the sums with 0, then you iterate over the arrays and check the condition and increment the sums accordingly.
You should run this code on the two arrays after you read them using cin. Good luck.

```
//init sums
int totala=0;
int totalb=0;
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  //check condition
  if(a[i]>b[i])
    totala++;
  else if(a[i] == b[i])
    continue;
  else
    totalb++;
}
```